# How to process files (e.g, edit images) before uploading to google drive with `rpldy/drive-uploady `?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, file-upload

I am using [`rpldy/drive-uploady`](https://github.com/rpldy/drive-uploady) to upload files to google drive. It works fine. However, I want to give a chance to user to edit the images and then upload. How do I do that?

Here is my current code

```
import DriveUploady from "drive-uploady";
import { UploadButton } from "@rpldy/upload-button";
...
...
        <DriveUploady
          clientId={CLIENT_ID}
          scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
          params={{ parents: [IMG_FOLDER_ID] }}
          accept="image/*"
          multiple>
          <UploadButton />
        </DriveUploady>
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, using `useUploady` hook from `@rpldy/uploady` worked like a charm.

```
export default function MyImgEditor() {
    const { upload } = useUploady();
    // process file and create blob and then
...
...
    return(
           ...
           <button
              onClick={() => {
                if (blob) {
                  upload(new File([blob], fileName));
                }
              }}>
              Upload
            </button>
   );
}
```

Make sure this component is wrapped inside `DriveUploady` like

```
<DriveUploady>
   <MyImgEditor />
</DriveUploady>
```